# SQL Query Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the following query that is failing and I don't understand why.  Clearly the column that the code is complaining about is in the table.

**Query:**

```
INSERT
  INTO `ProductAudit` (`Id`, `Field`, `OldValue`, `NewValue`, `ChangedOn`)
SELECT t.`ProductId`, 'Title', p.`Title`, t.`Title`, t.`ProcessedOn`
  FROM `TempImport` t
  LEFT JOIN `Product` p
    ON t.`ProductId` = p.`Id`
 WHERE p.`Title` != t.`Title`
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       p.`ChangedOn` = VALUES(`ChangedOn`)
```

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductAudit` (
  `Id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Field` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `OldValue` text,
  `NewValue` text,
  `ChangedOn` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Error:**

```
Error Code: 1054 - Unknown column 'p.ChangedOn' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you list the CREATE statement for is not the same table you are referencing in the query.  P is the Product table, not the ProductAudit table.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  If that solves your issue, I would suggest accepting the answer in order to close out the question.

Comment: To clarify the fault was with : `ProductAudit`.`ChangedOn` = VALUES(`ChangedOn`) rather than p.`ChangedOn`, in the ON DUPLICATE KEY part.  **however** now it is not populating anything in the table at all (even if the Product) table is empty.  Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: And yes, will close it in another 6 minutes :)

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the update Aaron.  It is good to know what works.

Answer (score 2):

In the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` phrase, you can only update the table which you are trying to insert into.